# unable to append data into existing excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm unable to append data into existing Excel sheet.
Here's my code:

```java
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
HSSFWorkbook wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
sheet1 = wb1.getSheet("sheet1");
System.out.println("Last Row No.: " + sheet1.getLastRowNum());
row = sheet1.createRow(sheet1.getLastRowNum()+ 1);
System.out.println("Last Row No.: " + sheet1.getLastRowNum());

row.createCell(0).setCellValue(2);          
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(2.2);
row.createCell(2).setCellValue(true);   

fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
wb1.write(fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 3):

The excel file format is not an appendable format. To write out changes, you must update the whole file.

Simply change your FileOutputStream to be a replacement rather than an append, and your code should then behave as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending using this code

```
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
sheet1 = wb1.getSheet("sheet1");
System.out.println("Last Row No.: " + sheet1.getLastRowNum());
row = sheet1.createRow(sheet1.getLastRowNum()+ 1);
System.out.println("Last Row No.: " + sheet1.getLastRowNum());

row.createCell(0).setCellValue(2);          
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(2.2);
row.createCell(2).setCellValue(true);   

fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
wb1.write(fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```